# array_merge in php on a single mutlidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I got an array here which differs in just one field[4].

Somehow my brains says use 'array_merge' but there is no usable result for me.

Can you please have a look?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => someCssClass
            [2] => AnyText
            [3] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
            [4] => 4,5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => someCssClass
            [2] => AnyText
            [3] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
            [4] => 6,7
        )
)
```

Below is what I think should be the output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => someCssClass
            [2] => AnyText
            [3] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
            [4] => 4,5,6,7
           )

)
```

Comment: So based on your brains thinking, have you tried `array_merge()`?

Comment: Assuming that the field [4] is a string, why don't just concatenate them?

Comment: Just have a loop on [4] and store it in string variable seperated by `,`

Answer (score 1):

If you know only **4 th** index is changed you can simply concatenate them

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => 12,
            1 => "someCssClass",
            2 => "AnyText",
            3 => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7",
            4 => "4,5"
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            0=> 12,
            1 => "someCssClass",
            2 => "AnyText",
            3 => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7",
            4 => "6,7"
        )
);
$new_array[] = $arr[0];
$new_array[0][4]=$arr[0][4].",".$arr[1][4];
print_r($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/3Jj7Z)

Answer (score 0):

You can not merge value by key because it could be anything, still you can merge array recursively by using `array_merge_recursive` function.

```
$ar1 = array(12, 'someclass','1,2,3,4,5,6,7','4,5');
$ar2 = array(12, 'someclass','1,2,3,4,5,6,7','6,7');
$result = array_unique(array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2));
print_r($result);
```